# Do computer viruses affect all user accounts on a computer?

Tags: virus

Do computer viruses affect all user accounts on a computer?

**IF a virus affects a local user will that effect administrator account and vise-versa?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Viruses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus) are all different and designed to do different things. The infection you were asking about in the other responder's message, "W32.Korgo.G",  is actually a [worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_worm). It exploits a vulnerability in the [LSASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Security_Authority_Subsystem_Service).

After digging through some of the [documentation on the worm at the Symantec site](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2004-052517-0616-99&tabid=2) I can safely say this does affect all users on the machine.

Since it's a worm it may have affected other machines on your network as well.

When a [virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus), [worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_worm), [trojan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_(computing)), [rootkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit), or any other type of [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) is installed, the privileges of the user account that was initially infected come into play. Some malware takes advantage of [exploits in operating systems and applications with higher privileges](https://www.exploit-db.com/local/) than the user and spreads that way throughout a machine. In other cases some malware may [spread to a shared folder or networked resource](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH122466.html) where it can infect other users. Some will [infect bios on the local machine](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2948092/security/hacking-teams-malware-uses-uefi-rootkit-to-survive-os-reinstalls.html). It really depends on the OS being used, the permissions of each user, the structures in place in the network and system where the infection takes place, and the method of infection.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on what the virus does.
But in most of the cases, it will affect all the user account.
I cant go into more details without talking about a specific virus.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.

If virus is of type W32 example: "W32.Korgo.G". will this affect all the user accounts?

Answer (score 0):

A Virus in general does not depend on the user account. Maybe read in [Wikipedia what a Virus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus) is.

Maybe you are more relating to [Malware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) that are often interested in information about the current user. An example is a [trojan horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_%28computing%29) trying to get access to your computer with the information of the logged users.

So in general a **virus does not depend on the user account and affects all the user**s. On the other hand a virus or **malsware often uses the information of the logged user**. So another user account may not be affected by a malware, but can => **depends on the malware/virus**.

Comment: Thanks for the replay.
 
Here i'm moving forward to remove the virus manually through regestry key deletion.

Here consider the scenario of virus of type W32 example: "W32.Korgo.G". will this affect all the user accounts?

will this creates registry keys in all the user accounts on the computer.

Comment: That Virus is not interested in user information and runs independent from the user. So the whole machine is affected and that means all users. See Symantec http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2004-060223-5826-99